# Get job from spooler - C++

Tags: c++, windows, printing

With a printer that doesn't exist, I send to the spooler different files. In my software, I try to get all files existing in the queue of the spooler. For that, I tried the following instruction:

```
 bool t = EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0,1,3, (LPBYTE) &h, sizeof(JOB_INFO_3), &pcbNeeded, &pcReturned)
```

I get jobId in the field 'JobId' of the structure.

In the structure type 'JOB_INFO_3', the field 'JobId' is well filled but the field 'nextJobId' is not filled. Why?

It's the same problem when I execute the following instruction:

```
bool t = EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0,3,3, (LPBYTE) &h, sizeof(JOB_INFO_3), &pcbNeeded, &pcReturned)
```

Moreover, the field 'JobId' is not filled. Why ?

Then, I don't know how to get info(filename, state, number of pages, etc) of a particular job. I tried the following instruction but it didn't work:

```
GetJobA(hPrinter, h.JobId, 1, (LPBYTE) &job_info_1, sizeof(JOB_INFO_1), & nbBytes)
```

And my last question is: Is it possible to get all the jobs from the spooler of the printer?

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Did my answer help at all? :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but it looks possible that you're not using the API quite correctly. The MSDN documentation suggests that you should call the `EnumJobs` API twice.

> To determine the required buffer size, call EnumJobs with cbBuf set to zero. EnumJobs fails, GetLastError returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, and the pcbNeeded parameter returns the size, in bytes, of the buffer required to hold the array of structures and their data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx

The flow goes like this:

1. Call `EnumJobs` for the first time to see how much memory needs to be allocated for your `JOB_INFO_n` array.
2. Allocate the memory required for your `JOB_INFO_n` array.
3. Call `EnumJobs` with your `JOB_INFO_n` array.

Looking at the call to EnumJobs where you attempt to get the first three jobs, the size of your `pJob` appears to be `sizeof(JOB_INFO_3)`, where it should be three times this size in order to hold all three jobs. What is the return from `EnumJobs` for that call?

The reason why `nextJobId` is not filled in is likely a misunderstanding of the field. This field is for print jobs that have been linked together, not to find out which print job is next in the queue.

> NextJobId - The print job identifier for the next print job in the linked set of print jobs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145021(v=vs.85).aspx

As for the information about the print job, this is going to be difficult. Unfortunately, there is no way I know of to get the name/path of the file printed. There's no concept of this in the spooler APIs. Consider a print job which isn't backed by a file for example. The best you get is the print job name, which is set by the printing application.

For pages, it looks like there is a `TotalPages` field in the `JOB_INFO_1` structure. That may be of some use to you. It looks like you're already trying to get the `JOB_INFO_1` structure but having some troubles. If the API is failing, you can use `GetLastError()` to identify what the issue is. Does the job ID you're passed in exist?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

For the last question about getting all print jobs from the queue. It seems that the MSDN documentation suggests the following:

> To determine the number of print jobs in the printer queue, call the GetPrinter function with the Level parameter set to 2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps.